# SQL Server GROUP BY dilemma

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with rows containing a column called `MySubId`. Values in this column can be duplicated. I want to find the `MySubId` value and the number of rows for the `MySubId` value that appears the most.

I have the following query:

```
SELECT MySubId, COUNT(MySubId) AS MySubIdCount
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY MySubId
HAVING COUNT(MySubId)=MAX(COUNT(MySubId))
```

But I get the error:

> Msg 130, Level 15, State 1, Line 4 Cannot perform an aggregate
>   function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

Is it not possible to do this with a simple query? Must I embed a subquery to calculate the MAX before using it in the `HAVING` clause?

**Update:**

I see a lot of anwers filtering the result set by using `TOP 1`, so am I to assume that there is no way to use the `MAX` function to filter this query to just the max appearing `MySubId` values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select top 1 with ties MySubId, Count(MySubId) as MySubIdCount
from MyTable
group by MuSubId
order by 2 desc
```

Comment: +1 for taking into consideration the possibility of multiple MySubIds sharing the same max count.

Comment: +1 Somehow I never knew that `with ties` existed and I've been doing this the hard way forever...

Answer (score 1):

```
select top 1 MySubId, Count(MySubId)
from MyTable
group by MySubId
order by count(MySubId) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just an FYI as I believe this would be the next logical step for the poster

If you want to delete all duplicates starting with the Newest...

```
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT
SET @ROWCOUNT = 1

WHILE @ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
     DELETE 
     FROM MyTable
     WHERE ID IN
     (
        SELECT MAX(ID)
        FROM MyTable
        GROUP By MySubID
        HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
     )
     SET @ROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (
    MySubId INT
)

INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (1)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (3)
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MySubId) VALUES (3)

;WITH Counts_CTE (MySubId, MySubIdCount, RowNumber)
AS
(
    SELECT 
        MySubId, 
        COUNT(MySubId) AS MySubIdCount,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(MySubId) DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM @MyTable
    GROUP BY MySubId
)
SELECT *
FROM Counts_CTE
WHERE RowNumber = 1
```